# Is there a way to connect my vpn in bat

Tags: windows-7, vpn

I am using windows7 ultimate x64 edition. And I have a VPN connection, every time when I connect to that vpn, system will ask me to input password

[image]

As you can see, windows says it will remember user name & password for "just me", but it does't.

I have two questions: 
1. How to make windows really remember VPN password? So I can just click a button to connect to VPN.

2. How to connect to a VPN in bat file?

Comment: The Windows VPN dialer *does* remember your credentials - the password box has a little message to enter your password or use the one it has remembered. You just need to click "Connect". The entry you have highlighted is for the connection to be available to all users of the computer - unless your VPN connection only uses one set of centigrade this isn't recommended. If you want to automate the connection you can use the Windows 7 built-in `rasdial.exe` in a script.

Comment: Thanks.@BigChris It's a little confusing, as the password box is empty, I always think I need to input my password.

Comment: @BigChris Actually you already answered all my two questions. rasdial.exe works for me. Please consider make your comment an answer. I will take it.

Comment: Credentials*. Not centigrade lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows VPN dialer *does* remember your credentials - the password box has a little message to enter your password or use the one it has remembered. You just need to click "Connect". The entry you have highlighted is for the connection to be available to all users of the computer. Unless your VPN connection only uses one set of credentials - or you really want to let others use your credentials - this isn't recommended. If you want to automate the connection you can use the Windows 7 built-in `rasdial.exe` in a script.